# Python "in" Keyword doesn't work properly. ignores some items in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to extract a few items from a list. all are strings. when I use "in" keyword with a list it doesn't work all the time.

```
['60 Seconds BITCOIN Technical Analysis', 'BTCUSD 8 Hours 21-02-24_17:24-23', 'SELL', '58000.00', '57000.00', '56000.00', '55000.00', '54000.00', '53000.00', '52000.00', '51000.00', '59397:39', 'D000.00', '43000.00', '47000.00', '45000.00', '15000.00', '42000.00', '- 41000.00', '40000.00', '39000.00', '38000.00', '37000.00', '36000.00', '35000.00', 'TRADE SUGGESTION', 'SELL : 50453.00', 'ТР : 50241.83', 'SL : 50633.72', '33000.00', '32000.00', '3 1000.00', '30000.00', '-29000.00', '28000.00', '27000.00', '26000.00', '18:30 02:30 18:30', '10:30 02:30 18:30', '10:30 02:30', '18:30', '10:30 02:30', '13:30 10:30 02:30 18:30 10:30 02:30', '10:30 02:30 18:30 10:30 02:30 18:30 10:30 02:30 18:30 10:30 02:30', '18:30 10:30 02:30 18:30 19:30 02:30', 'Trading At 50307.39']
```

this is the list I'm trying to extract from. So I use a for loop.

```
for i in str_list:
    if ("Technical" in i):
        signal["TC"] = i
    elif ("BUY :" in i):
        signal["BS"] = i
    elif "SL" in i:
        signal["SL"] = i
    elif ("Trading" in i):
        signal["TR"] = i
    elif ("TP" in i):
        signal["TP"] = i
    elif ("SELL :" in i):
        signal["BS"] = i
```

It always ignores random words. for example... most of the times "SL" or "TP". last time it returned this.

```
{'TC': '60 Seconds BITCOIN Technical Analysis', 'BS': 'SELL : 50453.00', 'SL': 'SL : 50633.72', 'TR': 'Trading At 50307.39'}
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check if changing from `elif` to `if` helps. if it does, then a single string has multiple valid cases, and the assignment is executed only for the first valid case.

Comment: In what exact way is this output wrong?  If it's the lack of a `"TP"` key in the dictionary, that's expected because I see no `TP` anywhere in the original list.

Comment: I'm not sure the use of this program, so what I'm saying could be of no relevance. But I also want to add that you are potentially overriding the "BS" key. Once with "BUY :" and once with "SELL :". Just something to keep in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly strange, this fails:

```
>>> "TP" in 'ТР : 50241.83'
False
```

But this works:

```
>>> "TP" in "TP"
True
```

This shows the reason, which is that the `T` and `P` are not latin unicode code points but are instead Cyrillic code points.

```
>>> for c in 'ТР : 50241.83':
...     print(unicodedata.name(c))
... 
CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER TE
CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ER
SPACE
COLON
SPACE
DIGIT FIVE
DIGIT ZERO
DIGIT TWO
DIGIT FOUR
DIGIT ONE
FULL STOP
DIGIT EIGHT
DIGIT THREE

>>> for c in "TP":
...     print(unicodedata.name(c))
... 
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
```

Answer (score 2):

Some characters in the strings are not ASCII characters, although they look like ones. For example, at index 27 the list contains the string

```
'ТР : 50241.83'
```

In this string both `T` and `P` are characters from the Cyrillic alphabet with Unicode code points U+0422 and U+0420 respectively. Thus, they do not match the ASCII string `TP`.